# Missing a positional argument

Tags: python-3.x

We're being forced to use multiple functions for something simple for an assignment to see the benefits of abstraction. I believe however that this unnecessarily complicates things (what do I know though?). I am missing a positional argument for my main composite function call though.

I haven't tried too much other than making the function return lists instead of tuples, but to no avail.

```py
import math


def calculations(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    difsqx = (x2 - x1) ** 2
    difsqy = (y2 - y1) ** 2

    return difsqx, difsqy


def square_rooter(difsqx, difsqy):
    distance = math.sqrt(difsqx + difsqy)

    return distance


def main():
    var1 = float(input("Enter an x1 value: "))
    var2 = float(input("Enter an x2 value: "))
    var3 = float(input("Enter a y1 value: "))
    var4 = float(input("Enter a y2 value: "))
    print(square_rooter(calculations(var1, var2, var3, var4)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am expecting to get the distance between (x1 & x2),  (y1 & y2), but I am getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/devon/PycharmProjects/Data Structures/In-Class Work/Cartesian Distance.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/devon/PycharmProjects/Data Structures/In-Class Work/Cartesian Distance.py", line 27, in main
    print(square_rooter([calculations(var1, var2, var3, var4)]))
TypeError: square_rooter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'difsqy'
```

Please send your highly trained monkeys to assist.

Comment: Note how many arguments `square_rooter` takes, and how many you're giving it. Also, I'd get used to using functions, as they ultimately make your life easier. Think about needing to use the code in `calculations` a hundred times. Would it be easier to calling the function, or write that code out each time? Its a good lesson to think about when to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [starred expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-starred-expression) to pass elements of a tuple as separate arguments to a function, since your `square_rooter` function needs two arguments:

```
print(square_rooter(*calculations(var1, var2, var3, var4)))
```